# iPhone Chinese simplified to traditional character conversion

Tags: iphone, localization, character, cjk

Is there a way to convert Chinese simplified characters to traditional characters in Cocoa/Objective-C? On the .NET platform you can include a VB dll in your projects that gives you access to a function for an easy conversion. Is there anything I can use in Cocoa/Objective-C that will allow me to do the same? I want to go between simplified and traditional and vice-versa. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As I know, Apple does not have public APIs to let you convert Chinese characters by simply calling a function, but you can do the conversion character by character your self.

The OpenVanilla project, an open source input method project, maintains a Chinese character conversion table. It was used in the input method software but I think it could also be used for other purposes. It is available at

- http://github.com/lukhnos/openvanilla-oranje/blob/master/Modules/OVOFHanConvert/VXHCSC2TCTable.c
- http://github.com/lukhnos/openvanilla-oranje/blob/master/Modules/OVOFHanConvert/VXHCTC2SCTable.c

Comment: Thank you very much. I was on a big deliverable for the past 2 weeks and was not able to get back to this. I have implemented my own conversion table since, as you suspect, there does not seem to exist a public API for such conversion. Thank you very much!

Comment: Old thread, I know, but I just stumbled onto it. Please note that there's no way to do a 100% accurate simplified to traditional conversion, as simplification caused mergers of characters that can't be reconstructed by a machine. See the characters for "noodle" and "face" in traditional, which have merged into one in simplified.